# How do I compare large numbers to small numbers in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I have to use the math.exp() function to get the following value for x which is converted to scientific notation. However, when trying to compare to see if this number is greater than y, python thinks it is less than.

```
x = 4.0686596698143466e+186
y = 59425800000000000000000
if x >= y:
    print:("x is greater than y")
```

I realize there are methods to turn very large numbers into smaller int but I feel that route is a little more complicated and above my learning curve than necessary. I just need a way to see if x > y and also curious why python doesn't support the comparison. Converting y to scientific notation using decimal only turns it into a string.

Disclaimer: still a beginner

Comment: Probably 1e186 cannot be representated by double floats ?

Comment: I've just tried what you say you did, and `x>=y` returns `True`.  What exactly is your problem?  Moreover, your code exhibits a syntax error, namely `print:`.

Comment: @gboffi Yep, mixed it up with single precision.

Comment: Sure enough the syntax error got me. Thanks @gboffi
Why didn't python throw an error?

In the meantime I learned the split function.
`str(x).split("+")[1]`